# How to get access to inherited object properties in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inheritance

The case is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    int Id{get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Legal))]
public class Info
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Legal : Info
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Legal))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int DoWork(Info dto);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{

    public int DoWork(Info dto)
    {
        string name;
        if (dto is Legal)
            name = (dto as Legal).ManagerName;
        return dto.Id;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to know the dto as Legal type and have access to the child properties?

I want to store the dto and I don't want to have many services for each child of info.

Passing Generics to service doesn't work, wsdl error,
Interface such as IInfo as input parameter doesn't work, casting error,
Base class like Info doesn't work, child props are not accessible,
stack overflow doesn't work, this is my 2nd time i post this prob but no answer!

Comment: Did you try to host the service regardless of the errors you get in WCFHost-Tool? In some complicated scenarios this tool is "lying" to you. If you deploy it to IIS for instance everything works fine. I'll try out your sample as soon as I can! Stay tuned.

Comment: Tried your sample. It works for me. Is your sample-code working and you wan't to do something else? Could you post a sample that won't work for you?

Comment: that was my exact sample dude! i'll gonna try it on iis so soon, tnx for suggestion. any mail address?

Comment: Didn't work on IIS. the error is:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'WebApplication.Dtos.IInfo

My Sample code is exactly pasted above.

Comment: I don't see the sense of your IInfo interface, it is never used (not implemented by Info or declared by DoWork), plus, it hat an ServiceContract attribute, but contains a member with a DataMember attribute, this doesn't fit.

Comment: you are right Hinek, that interface was a part of my test code. Info had been implementing it previously, and IInfo was the type of input argument of DoWork. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm passing a json as dto to MyService.
If i add "__type":"Legal:#Dto", MyService recognize the dto as Legal.
then (dto as Legal).ManagerName has value

This solution is working, actually passing __type is not handy way. I'll appreciate your better suggestions.